# How to get Continuous live streaming without buffering in azure media player using FFMPEG(Latency is not a issue)?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp, live-streaming, azure-media-services

I am streaming from the ip camera which uses RTSP protocol and ingesting the feed to RTMP(to Azure media server) using the following command

> `ffmpeg command` : ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://CloudAppUser:admin@192.168.8.145/MediaInput/h264/stream_1 -vcodec libx264 -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://channel1-cloudstream-inso.channel.media.azure.net:1934/live/980b582afc12e421b85b4jifd8e8662b/df

I am able to watch the stream but it is buffering once in every 30 seconds , and I want to know the reason behind this buffering

Please any one change this command , so that it should not buffer

I am executing this command from my terminal

I would like to watch my live stream in azure media player without any buffering and latency below 1 minute is not an issue

Comment: Have you checked the server resources to make sure it's not being depleted? ffmpeg is resource intensive and that could cause "buffering".

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-configure-wirecast-live-encoder), when on-premise encoders are set up to push a contribution feed into a Channel, we recommend that these encoders use fixed 2 second GOPs. If your IP camera is not sending 2 second GOPs, you'd have to modify the ffmpeg commandline to re-encode the input video bitstream, and not just copy it. If that doesn't help, recommend contacting us via amshelp@microsoft.com with the (output) stream URL, and other details like the Media Service account name, region used, and date/time/timezone you attempted to stream the feed.

Comment: Can you please change my ffmpeg command  : ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://CloudAppUser:admin@192.168.8.145/MediaInput/h264/stream_1 -vcodec libx264 -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://channel1-cloudstream-inso.channel.media.azure.net:1934/live/980b582afc12e421b85b4jifd8e8662b/df